# Paginating MySql Results

Tags: php, javascript

I have a table that pulls tickets from a MYSQL database and displays them to the user. This part works wonderfully! But, once the user gets 5-10 tickets, the page becomes long and ugly. I am wanting to paginate the responses automatically to show maybe `5` tickets per page and show the rest on following pages.

I am using Bootstrap and have the following for the display of the pagination. "Although I fear this is only pseudo code" I added id's to each main element.

```
<ul class="pager" id="pagerUL">
    <li class="previous" id="previousUL">
        <a href="#">&larr; Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="next" id="nextUL">
        <a href="#">Next &rarr;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Essentially the only code used to pull the database information on the page is:

```
<?php if(count($tickets) > 0) : ?>
     <?php foreach ($tickets as $ticket): ?>
        //table content 
     <?php endforeach ?>
<?php else : ?>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="7">No Tickets Created.</td>
     </tr>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

I thought we could add something to the `<?php if(count($tickets) > 0) : ?>` But honestly, I am not sure as I am not a expert at php and never even attempted or had the need to build pagination up until now. Any help, guidance, thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: check it out http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: What then? I don't get. Pagination simply requires some links (depending upon your requirements they may be buttons in rare cases) which when clicked cause  appropriate values to be supplied which can be used in SQL to retrieve a sublist of rows. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the page number thru the URL and then grab it via php with $_GET.

```
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 $per_page = 10; // Define it as you please
 $start = $page*$per_page;

 $query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ".$start.", ".$per_page;
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result); 
 $i = 0;

 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 {
    //echo out what you want
    echo "";
 }

 $total_pages = ceil($count/$per_page);

 for($i=0;$i<$total_pages;$i++)
 {
    if($page != $i)
    {
       echo "<a href='/page.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    } else
    {
       echo $i;
    }
 }
```